# SQL combining rows into one

Tags: sql

I currently have two tables that I would like together to query.
One has file numbers that is seen by the user, and it joined to the second table by the fileID.

The second table consists of 3 columns . The fileID, an ID that shows which of 12 options for the field that the data will be in, along with the data that is in each corresponding field.
The second table has each fileID showing 12 times, for each field type. I want the end query to return all in one row; the file number, and then data of each 12 fields.

Currently when I query it returns 12 different rows per file number. Is there a way to just get 1 row with all the relevant information?

Current Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.FileNumber
    , CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 1 THEN t2.value END 
    , CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 2 THEN t2.value END 
    , CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 3 THEN t2.value END 
    , CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 4 THEN t2.value END 

FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.fileID = t2.fileID

ORDER BY t1.FileNumber
```

I didn't go through with all 12 data types as I was just testing with 4 when I saw the duplicate rows.

Comment: Yes.  What is your current query?  What is the current result?  What is the desired result?  Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.FileNumber,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 1 THEN t2.value END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 2 THEN t2.value END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 3 THEN t2.value END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.typeID = 4 THEN t2.value END)
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.fileID = t2.fileID
GROUP BY t1.FileNumber
ORDER BY t1.FileNumber;
```